# Using Google App engine for python/html web posting and sending automated email

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, post

Quick question, I m developing (n learning) a simple app whereby the user posts a comment to my webapp on GAE, and i will reply with an automated email (in Python).. Not sure where i got it wrong but was wondering whether anyone can help or guide me along?

Done a quick code snippets with some modifications from code.google.com

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

from google.appengine.api import mail

class MyRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('''
        <html>
          <body>
            <form action="post">
              <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
              <p>Email: <input type="test" name="email" /></p>
              <p>Comments / Inputs: <input type="text" name="comments" /></p>
            </form>
          </body>
        </html>
        ''')

    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get("name")
        comment = self.request.get_range("comment")


message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="Support <contactus@support.com>",
                            subject="Thanks for your feedback")

message.to = self.request.get("email")

message.body = """
Hi there,

Thanks for your comment. We will get back to you soon.

Please let us know if you have any questions.


"""

message.send()
```

Comment: Seems like there's some issue with the google.appengine.ext

Comment: forgot to add the part where the object has been created:myrequest= MyRequestHandler(webapp)
myrequest.get(myrequest)
myrequest.post(myrequest)

Comment: are you really using `contactus@support.com` as the sender address?

Comment: @hz You've described what you're trying to do, but you haven't actually said what the problem is. There's no way we can help unless you tell us that, and include any exception stacktraces you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

I think ur indentation is wrong. Also give ids to ur input elements Try this

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

from google.appengine.api import mail

class MyRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('''
        <html>
          <body>
            <form action="post">
              <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></p>
              <p>Email: <input type="test" name="email" id="email" /></p>
              <p>Comments / Inputs: <input type="text" name="comments" /></p>
            </form>
          </body>
        </html>
        ''')

    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get("name")
        comment = self.request.get_range("comment")


        message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="Support <contactus@support.com>",
                            subject="Thanks for your feedback")

        message.to = self.request.get("email")

        message.body = """
                       Hi there,

                       Thanks for your comment. We will get back to you soon.

                       Please let us know if you have any questions.


                      """    
        message.send()
```

Comment: Made changes, but doesnt seem to work... did i miss out on anything?

Comment: Yes as the second answer suggests u should put post in method and ur url in action in the FORM's attributes

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've mixed up the action and method form attributes.  Try:

```
<form action="<your url here>" method="post">
```